# Help finding id of built in wireless card

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've tried the following codes below on my Nuvision TM800W610L tablet, none of which show any results.

```
lspci -nn | grep Net

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

All I know about the wireless chip is that it is a broadcom inside the tablet. Under windows 10 it showed up as "broadcom 802.11n wireless SDIO adapter (1.576.12.0)"
Using a Wifi usb stick I did manage to use the following code which did work on my first installation of Ubuntu 18.10

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

I reinstalled ubuntu 18.10 and the tablet's built in wifi no longer works when I unplug the wifi usb stick this time around. I tried reinstalling ubuntu about 3 more times using the same codes above but no dice. Ubuntu doesn't doesn't show any wifi options. Not sure how it worked the first time around. Everything looks fine in the bios.

Edit:

```
@poketab:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)

@poketab:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0002 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0101:0007  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

dmesg | grep brcm; ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars | grep -i nvram
[    6.313784] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd failed with error -2
[    6.313794] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd not found
[    6.551966] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio for chip BCM43430/0
[    6.552315] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    6.568819] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[    7.569961] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113
```

NOTE: In Bios I see BCM4356 listed as a WLAN and it's enabled. Not sure if that means that's the specific chipset for wifi as it seems like that is a wireless AC chip but I believe the tablet is listed as a wireless N chip. I could be wrong though.

Comment: please post the `lspci` output without any grep.. shouldn't be much.

Comment: added lspci results in my question.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb`.

Comment: added lsusb results in my question

Comment: There is no working wireless adapter anywhere.

Comment: It was working the first time I installed ubuntu on the tablet. Not sure why the wireless chip doesn't show up anymore. That's what I'm trying to figure out. I'll keep digging and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0002 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd`: is that your USB wifi stick?  Also, what device are you installing on? You mentioned a "tablet", OK, what tablet is this?

Comment: Please edit to include results for `dmesg | grep brcm; ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars | grep -i nvram`

Comment: Added all information above and all codes are being typed in without the wifi usb stick pplugged in to avoid confusion with the built in wifi. Not sure what Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0002 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd is.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt
```

For other SDIO devices replace `brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt` with the name that appears in dmesg results

That will get the firmware needed by your wifi, reboot and it should be usuable

If you want to know the ID's for the wifi

```
sudo cat /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 | egrep -i 'vendid|prodid'
```

This is a SDIO card connected to the SDIO bus, they are mentioned on https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211 and the firmware install is covered under https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211#firmware_installation1
There have been some issues with computers that do not have a nvram file in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars and then a search for the firmware filename can be done and hope that what is found works, copying the nvram file has no problems and I am not sure why the kernel devs just didn't have the module look for the nvram file to begin with

Comment: Can you explain how the adapter is connected and why this copying should work?

Comment: @Pilot6, explanation added