# No wireless device in Lubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

I have exactly the same problem as in "[Help finding id of built in wireless card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123405/help-finding-id-of-built-in-wireless-card)", only it's a notebook not a tablet. I'm trying to install Lubuntu 19.10 but the internal wireless device is not detected.
There are no relevant entries in lspci or lsusb. But in my case there is also no nvram file in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Laptop is a Jumper EzBook 2. It came with Windows 10 pre-installed and wireless adapter was recognized by Windows as "Broadcom 802.11n wireless SDIO adapter" and was working properly. I have completely erased the Windows installation and I'm trying to install a Linux distro. Nothing I have tried so far recognized the wireless adapter.

`lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)

00:16.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b7 (rev 22)

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)`

`lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1018:1006

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13fe:3123 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Verbatim STORE N GO 4GB

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b336 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub

Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter

Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Device 013 is an external USB Ethernet adapter used temporarily to have Internet access.

`ubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i firm
[    0.221529] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.485857] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[   23.714678] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd failed with error -2
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i sdio
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i brcm
[   23.714678] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd failed with error -2
[   23.714695] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd not found`

Comment: Just added output of lspci, lsusb, dmesg

Comment: If no wireless adapter found, it probably was configured without one. If you click [edit] and provide the make and model, we can find the tech specs to confirm that, and if that's the case, you'd need to add one (internal or external). If it was sold with a wireless adapter, it might have been removed by the original owner (if bought used) or might need to be disconnected then reconnected to solve a loose connection.

Comment: Check BIOS settings, see if wlan is disabled

Comment: I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide (the device recognition and operation  link I find most helpful, it helps you to recognize your card & search online, plus provide details for us).  I'd suggest following Jeremy31's advice first though

Comment: In BIOS there is a setting for BCM4356 which is enabled.

Comment: Added some more info about the laptop.

Comment: Plese edit to add result for `dmesg |grep brcm`

Comment: It's already there, 3 last lines